# Wordpress Transfer issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this website created with wordpress on http://schoolcms.webfreaks.cu.cc/
It is working perfectly fine on this host but when I try to transfer it any other other host (even localhost) it gives me layout issues like this: http://consciousnesstree.com/sharadashram/
Am I doing something wrong or the website transfer creating some issues?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming problem. It seems more suited for [webmasters.se] or [wordpress.se].

Comment: The WordPress codex has detailed instructions for [moving a WordPress site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of css which is not properly adding in your localhost . Also one more thing I mentioned you , Steps when any Wordpress site moves to another domain or localhost , which recovers almost all minor issuses :

1. Change home_url , site_url and some times permalink in your database 'wp_options' table.
2. If database name has been changed then you have to change some parameters like database name , host , user and password in wp_config.php.
3. Also make sure if any url was given in previous domain written in hard coded then you have to change too manually.

I hope it helps you .
For any further assistance feel free to revert me.

Comment: Ok, as I have said already there is  issue of css . I have seen your both sites . I found one thing there are multiple css including and in other hosting your css location after clicking to send another domain please check this line . hint : 

<link rel='stylesheet' id='pt-cv-bootstrap-style-group-css' href='http://schoolcms.webfreaks.cu.cc/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/plugins/content-views-query-and-display-post-page/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css......../>
Please check your css line .

Comment: Ohh, Okay. Let me check on it.

Answer (score 0):

I also have got that issue and solve that using duplicator plugin. I think that is the easiest way to fix your problem. You can download and see how it works in [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)